# Find Duplicates in a Column with a Variable Range and Count in a Separate Column

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I'm trying to identify any duplicates in a column that is a variable range. I found this code:

```
Public Sub assignSeq()

targetRng = "A2:A14" 'Define the Range you want to assign number

For Each Rng In Range(targetRng)

Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 

Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Split(targetRng, ":")(0) & ":" & Rng.Address), Rng.Value)

Next

End Sub
```

I tried to modify it hoping that I could use it to work for a column that will have a variable range (I will be using this code along with other code in many workbooks so I can't have it with a set range, i.e. E2:E15).

```
Sub assignSeq()

Dim lastRow As Long

Dim targetRng As Range

Dim rng As Range

'Column E won't be the same length every file that this macro is ran in. Column B is used to tell how long column E is.

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'Define the Range you want to assign number

Set targetRng = Range("E2:E5" & lastRow)

Set rng = Range("E2:E5" & lastRow)

 For Each rng In Range("E2:E5" & lastRow)
 rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 

Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Split(targetRng, ":")(0) & ":" & rng.Address), rng.Value)

 Next

End Sub
```

When I run the code I get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

Below, **Column F** is what I want this code to do all the way down the column no matter how long it is.
Column G is done by a separate code that I have written and works so I'm not necessarily looking for help with that but rather I was wanting to show what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish.

```
Column E           Column F     Column G  

PermAssetNumber    Count        PermAssetNumber w/Count
B02061               1          B02061
B02061               2          B02061_2
B02079               1          B02079
B02081               1          B02081
B02081               2          B02081_2
B02063               1          B02063
B02070               1          B02070
B02062               1          B02062
B02081               3          B02081_3
B02086               1          B02086
B02087               1          B02087
B02088               1          B02088
B02089               1          B02089
B02090               1          B02090
B02091               1          B02091
B02065               1          B02065
B02082               1          B02082
B02083               1          B02083
B02048               1          B02048
B02081               4          B02081_4
```

Comment: You could do this with a simple formula - why the need for VBA?

Comment: As @SJR said - you could use `=$E2 & "_" & COUNTIF($E$2:$E2, $E2)` in cell G2 and drag down. It would number `_1` but you could use an `IF` statement to check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

- You had some typos `Range("E2:E5" & lastRow)` - the 5 was an error.
- `Split(targetRng, ":")` is wrong because `Targetrng` is a range not a string so  we use its `Address` property which is a string.

  ```
  Sub assignSeq()

  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim targetRng As Range
  Dim rng As Range

  lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

  Set targetRng = Range("E2:E" & lastRow)

  For Each rng In targetRng
      rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Split(targetRng.Address, ":")(0) & ":" & rng.Address), rng.Value)
  Next

  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime duplicate counts are involved, I use the `dictionary object`. The dictionary is an enhanced `hashtable` that allows only unique key-value pairs. Below is an example that you can modify to fit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunningCounts(ByVal strWBName As String, ByVal strWSName As String, _
                         ByVal strTargteRngAddress As String, ByVal strColToFindLR As String)

 Dim objDict As Object
 Dim objWB As Workbook
 Dim objWS As Worksheet
 Dim rngToLookUp As Range
 Dim lngLastRow As Long, i As Long
 Dim arrySheet As Variant, arryOut() As Variant
 Dim varKey As Variant

    Set objWB = Workbooks(strWBName)
    Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets(strWSName)
    lngLastRow = objWS.Cells(objWS.Rows.Count, strColToFindLR).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngToLookUp = objWS.Range(strTargteRngAddress & lngLastRow)

    If rngToLookUp.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "The input Range cannot be more than" _
        & " a single column.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error:" _
        & " Invalid Range Dimensions"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    arrySheet = rngToLookUp.Value2

        ReDim arryOut(1 To UBound(arrySheet, 1), 1 To 1)

        Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

            For i = LBound(arrySheet, 1) To UBound(arrySheet, 1)
                'each time a key occurs, add one to the item associated with that key
               varKey = Trim(arrySheet(i, 1))
               If Not objDict.Exists(varKey) Then
                  objDict(varKey) = 1
                  arryOut(i,1) = 1
               Else
                  objDict(varKey) = objDict(varKey) + 1  
                  arryOut(i,1) = objDict.Item(varKey)             
               End If
               varKey = Empty 
            Next i

    rngToLookUp.Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(arryOut, 1), _
    UBound(arryOut, 2)).Value2 = arryOut

End Sub


Public Sub ExecuteRunningCount()

 Dim strTgtWBName As String
 Dim strgtWSName As String
 Dim strTgtRangeAddress As String
 Dim strTgtColToLookInLR As String

    strTgtWBName = "SomeWBNamew.xlsm" 
    strTgtWSName = "SheetName"
    strTgtRangeAddress = "A2:A"
    strTgtColToLookInLR = "A"

    Call RunningCounts(strTgtWBName, strTgtWSName, strTgtRangeAddress, strTgtColToLookInLR )

End Sub
```